# Unexpected use of 'event' on Login

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I'm running a react-create-app and it's giving me the following errors on my below `Login.js`

```
./src/components/Login/Login.js
  Line 6:  'handleClick' is not defined  no-undef
  Line 6:  Unexpected use of 'event'     no-restricted-globals
```

I've tried moving the `handleClick` event elsewhere in the js file but I continue to get the same error.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import {Button, Checkbox, Col, ControlLabel, Form, FormControl, FormGroup} from 'react-bootstrap';
import './Login.css';

handleClick(event)
{
    const username = this.refs.username;
    const password = this.refs.password;
    const creds = { username: username.value.trim(), password: password.value.trim() };
    this.props.onLoginClick(creds)
}

Login.propTypes = {
    onLoginClick: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    errorMessage: PropTypes.string
};

class Login extends Component {
    render() {
        const { errorMessage } = this.props;

        return (
            <Form horizontal>
                <FormGroup controlId="formHorizontalEmail">
                    <Col componentClass={ControlLabel} sm={2}>
                        Email
                    </Col>
                    <Col sm={10}>
                        <FormControl type="email" placeholder="Email" />
                    </Col>
                </FormGroup>

                <FormGroup controlId="formHorizontalPassword">
                    <Col componentClass={ControlLabel} sm={2}>
                        Password
                    </Col>
                    <Col sm={10}>
                        <FormControl type="password" placeholder="Password" />
                    </Col>
                </FormGroup>

                <FormGroup>
                    <Col smOffset={2} sm={10}>
                        <Checkbox>Remember me</Checkbox>
                    </Col>
                </FormGroup>

                <FormGroup>
                    <Col smOffset={2} sm={10}>
                        <Button onClick={(event) => this.handleClick(event)} type="submit">Sign in</Button>
                    </Col>
                </FormGroup>
                {errorMessage &&
                <p style={{color:'red'}}>{errorMessage}</p>
                }
            </Form>
        );
    }
}

export default Login;
```

Comment: Make `handleClick` a method of the class, not outside of it, you lose the entire scope

Comment: even if I put it at the end right before `export default Login;` it still shows as not defined

Comment: weird I had to explicitly call `function` before handleClick and had to remove `this.` from where it was called in the return.

Answer (score 0):

This ended up working:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import {Button, Checkbox, Col, ControlLabel, Form, FormControl, FormGroup} from 'react-bootstrap';
import './Login.css';

class Login extends Component {
    render() {
        const { errorMessage } = this.props;

        Login.propTypes = {
            onLoginClick: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
            errorMessage: PropTypes.string
        }

        function handleClick(event) {
            const username = this.refs.username;
            const password = this.refs.password;
            const creds = { username: username.value.trim(), password: password.value.trim() };
            this.props.onLoginClick(creds)
        }

        return (
            <Form horizontal>
                <FormGroup controlId="formHorizontalEmail">
                    <Col componentClass={ControlLabel} sm={2}>
                        Email
                    </Col>
                    <Col sm={10}>
                        <FormControl type="email" placeholder="Email" />
                    </Col>
                </FormGroup>

                <FormGroup controlId="formHorizontalPassword">
                    <Col componentClass={ControlLabel} sm={2}>
                        Password
                    </Col>
                    <Col sm={10}>
                        <FormControl type="password" placeholder="Password" />
                    </Col>
                </FormGroup>

                <FormGroup>
                    <Col smOffset={2} sm={10}>
                        <Checkbox>Remember me</Checkbox>
                    </Col>
                </FormGroup>

                <FormGroup>
                    <Col smOffset={2} sm={10}>
                        <Button onClick={(event) => handleClick(event)} type="submit">Sign in</Button>
                    </Col>
                </FormGroup>
                {errorMessage &&
                <p style={{color:'red'}}>{errorMessage}</p>
                }
            </Form>
        )
    }
}

export default Login;
```

Comment: This is still a bad practice. Move it INSIDE the class, make it a class method

Comment: fixed I moved it inside the class

Answer (score 0):

Moving `handleClick` inside the class fixes the error:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import {Button, Checkbox, Col, ControlLabel, Form, FormControl, FormGroup} from 'react-bootstrap';
import './Login.css';

Login.propTypes = {
    onLoginClick: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    errorMessage: PropTypes.string
};

class Login extends Component {
    handleClick(event)
    {
        const username = this.refs.username;
        const password = this.refs.password;
        const creds = { 
          username: username.value.trim(),
          password: password.value.trim()
        };
        this.props.onLoginClick(creds)
    }

    render() {
        const { errorMessage } = this.props;

        return (
            <Form horizontal>
                <FormGroup controlId="formHorizontalEmail">
                    <Col componentClass={ControlLabel} sm={2}>
                        Email
                    </Col>
                    <Col sm={10}>
                        <FormControl type="email" placeholder="Email" />
                    </Col>
                </FormGroup>

                <FormGroup controlId="formHorizontalPassword">
                    <Col componentClass={ControlLabel} sm={2}>
                        Password
                    </Col>
                    <Col sm={10}>
                        <FormControl type="password" placeholder="Password" />
                    </Col>
                </FormGroup>

                <FormGroup>
                    <Col smOffset={2} sm={10}>
                        <Checkbox>Remember me</Checkbox>
                    </Col>
                </FormGroup>

                <FormGroup>
                    <Col smOffset={2} sm={10}>
                        <Button onClick={(event) => this.handleClick(event)} type="submit">Sign in</Button>
                    </Col>
                </FormGroup>
                {errorMessage &&
                <p style={{color:'red'}}>{errorMessage}</p>
                }
            </Form>
        );
    }
}

export default Login;
```